# Cannot access Firestore data on Angular after Anonymous SignIn

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set rules on Firebase. These are the rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Credentials/{CredId} {
      allow read;
      allow write:if request.auth!=null;
    }
    match /Staffs/{StaffId} {
    allow read, write:if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

On Angular, I have imported AngularFireAuth: `import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';`

and in constructor: `private auth:AngularFireAuth`

then signing in the user by: `this.auth.signInAnonymously();`

Later when I'm trying to access the data by:

```
    this.store.collection("Staffs").get().subscribe(data=>{
      data.forEach(el=>{
        console.log(el);
      });
    },error=>this.service.ShowError(error.message));
```

I'm getting an error Missing or Insufficient Permissions. Please help me find what am I missing here?

Edit with complete code:

Signing In:

```
      this.store.doc("Credentials/admin").get().subscribe(data=>{
        this.credential=<Credential>data.data();
        if(this.credential.password==sha256(this.password))
        {
          this.auth.signInAnonymously().then(data=>console.log(data.user?.uid));
          this.router.navigateByUrl("admin");
        }
        else
        {
          this.toastr.error("Wrong password");
          this.username="";
          this.password="";
        }
      },error=>this.service.ShowError(error.message));
```

Trying to fetch data, where I am getting an error:

```
this.store.collection("Staffs").get().subscribe(data=>{
      data.forEach(el=>{
        let staff=new Staff("","","","");
        staff=<Staff><unknown>el.data();
        staff.staffId=el.id;
        this.Staffs.push(staff);
      });
    },error=>this.service.ShowError(error.message));
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are logged in by logging your UID before making call to Firestore?

Comment: I changed the sign in code to this: `this.auth.signInAnonymously().then(data=>console.log(data.user?.uid));` and got a response as `nBpdjvqIAldf4esjRsudh5TMaUR2` @Dharmaraj

Comment: Can you share the complete code? Just to make sure all promises are handled correctly.

Comment: I have made edits with complete code.

Comment: I doubt if the Firestore request is running before you are logged in. If you are trying to fetch data right after login then you should try adding the query inside of `.then()` block of sign in.

Comment: I put the Firestore request inside the `.then()` block, but it's still giving the error. I also tried setting persistence to local by `this.auth.setPersistence('local').then(()=>{this.auth.signInAnonymously()});` .

Answer (score 0):

After an exhaustive search, I found that the issue was with the firebase version. Fixed it by downgrading firebase to 8.3.0 by `npm i firebase@8.3.0 --save`.

To read more about the issue:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2857

Thanks, @Dharmaraj for your time.